# how to look for a specific difference between two numbers in multiple numbers

Tags: difference

I am trying to identify a specific difference between two numbers in a list of multiple numbers. For example, if I have a list 1, 3, 23, 66, 45, 73 I want to look for a difference of 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithm to find all pairs whose difference is D.

Let N be the list of numbers where N[i] is the i'th number in the list for i = 1 to M.

1. Sort N in increasing order.
2. Keep track of two indexes i and j on N.
3. Set i = 1, j = 1.
4. For each i, increment j until either N[i] + D = N[j] or j is maximum without N[i] + D getting greater than N[j]. If N[i] + D = N[j] then a pair (N[i] N[j]) has been found. Continue with next i.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!